# Does telegram-cli require api_id api_hash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, telegram, telethon

I am trying to understand why telegram-cli doesn't require api_id and api_hash and only require phone a number while another library (telethon) which I actually use requires api_id and api_hash?

Are there any ways to use the telethon with a phone number only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it already hard-coded in configure file named [TELEGRAM_CLI_APP_HASH](https://git.io/vFEqd).

Comment: But why did they do it? I thought it is personal information

Comment: @UserKa I think it's for convenience, just like Web version client don't need to enter they again.